# how move specific files (already pushed changes) from one branch to a new branch in android studio?

Tags: android, git, android-studio, github, branch

I am currently working on my android application on android studio and I am fairly new to working on it with git. I have files that I want to move from a branch **(branch1)** to a completely new branch **(feature1)**. Please note that I have committed all of my changes to **branch1** and I have pushed all of those commits as well.

I have seen similar questions with answers but I am quite confused about how to make it work. How can I do that? Thank you and pls bear with me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say we have three branch in a repository (master, branch1, branch2).

Now, you want to remove file from `branch1` and that file should be present in a completely new branch *say* `branch3`

1. Create new branch of `branch1`

   `git checkout branch1` //to create new branch from branch1, you need to checkout to that branch first

   `git checkout -b branch3`

Now, the new files are in `branch3`.

Now checkout to `branch1` and `$ git rm <file-name>` and `$ git commit -m "file removed from branch"`

It's the simple and straightforward way I can think of.

Answer (score 0):

You can cherry pick commit that you want to move from branch1 to feature1